# How to create an ownerdrawn control in silverlight 4?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, controls

Can't find a good explanation on how to create a simple ownerdrawn control in Silverlight.

Let's say I want to create an "Arch" or a "Line" control.

What should be my base class?

How do I get access to the drawing context so my code can render the graphics?

I see that FrameworkElement in Silverlight doesn't provide much help here.  What are the best practices?

Thanks

Update:  The reason that I'm asking this is very simple - I'm building a virtual (unlimited) surface that can be scrolled in any direction that should show visualize a lot of data. Something like diagramming. I'm planning to start with something very simple that is similar to the Familiy.Show (http://familyshow.codeplex.com/). That diagram implementation is solely WPF and rendered solely through OnRender(DrawingContext) paradigm.

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me what you want your control to do? like a button?

Comment: It would be easier had you stated __why__ you want an ownerdrawn control perhaps including a concrete description of one such control.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a control taking responsibility for drawing pixels on the surface of a rectangle it owns is alien to Silverlight.

Since you include the term "best practice" I'm going to extrapolate heuristically that you want to build custom controls that generate their UI entirely from primitive operations.

Create a new "Custom Templated Control".  In the `ControlTemplate` added to the "themes/generic.xaml" you can now include the Xaml that specifically describes UI you need.

Silverlight supports elements able to descibe fundemental components that derive from `Shape` such as an `Elipse` (which can also draw an arc), `Line`, `Rectangle`, `Polygon` and `Polyline`.  A `Path` can also be used describe more complex shapes that may include `Bezier` segments.